# Can I call a lombok getter in source code?

Tags: java, lombok, getter-setter

I imported everything according to the Projectlombok site into my project.

I wonder if it is possible to call the getters and other things generated by Lombok right in the source code? I've tested that the JSON serializer can access these after compiling, but I can't use them in the project.

For example:

```
@Getter
class Person {
    String name;
}

class MyClass {
    void f(Person p) {
         p.getName(); // doesn't compile for me
    }
}
```

Tell me if I am wrong that Lombok can be used for this purpose.

Comment: If it does not compile then json serializer cannot access it either. What you are most likely asking instead is how to tell your IDE to understand lombok. That depends on your IDE.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Lombok enhances the class at compile time, and adds that getter. So, if Lombok is properly configured/used, this will work just fine.

Comment: 'at compile time' means before or after the java compiler, which obviously runs at compile time also?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri Lombok is an annotation processor, which is executed by the Java compiler *during* compilation. The end result is that the code is compiled as if that getter was present in the source code.

Comment: @luk2302 is right. Simply install the plugin for your IDE. You can find the right plugin in the plugin management of your IDE or on the lombok site [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) -> Install -> IDEs

Comment: If it doesn't work you may have not enable annotation processing, or your IDE does not recognize Lombok.

Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) and Maven, and I have set up everything I found on the Lombok website. I work at a company where I'm a junior. The company has its framework and the project I'm working on builds up from many modules, maybe I should put maven dependency not just into the library project but into all projects where I use the getter-setters? That may be not possible for me to do such changes in some common projects... Anyways I don't know if this problem is related to that.

Comment: @KASMIG. (I left out the tag)